# ¿Puedo hacer mi propio web builder de esta manera?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi idea es hacer una aplicación web y luego en la parte del back end hacer un panel para maquetar el diseño, digamos que solo me interesa el contenido, es decir se añade texto, iconos, imagenes etc pero la barra de nav, footer, sidebars no se tocan.

La idea es que pueda elegir por ejemplo las filas que va a tener y luego dentro de las filas las columnas y dentro de la columna el contenido.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Puedo hacer eso con simples formularios que vayan añadiendo código html a una tabla en la base de datos MySQL y luego en la página simplemente hacer algo como:

navbar estatico

$htmlgenerado

footer estatico

Todavía estoy aprendiendo PHP y MySQL pero como ya se manejar tema de obtener datos de formularios y pasarlos a la base de datos pues me vino esa idea.

Me gustaria al hacerlo llevarlo a un control de versiones y hacerlo open source ya que solamente es por aprender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola si si puedes es bastante sencillo aunque recomendaría el uso de algun sistema de plantillas, pero en fin lo que necesitas es escribir 2 html uno con el header `header.html` y el otro con el pie statico que vas definir `footer.php` luego 
en tu archivo `.php`

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('ruta de header.html'); ?>
// Aqui en medio pon tu codigo
<?php echo file_get_contents('ruta de footer.html'); ?>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Sobre el tema usar un sistema de control de versiones aprende GIT es bastante facil, te dejo un enlace al manual en español [Libro GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1). En base a ello solo tienes que elegir un repositorio publico donde subirlo:

[GitHub](https://github.com)

[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

[Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home/)

GitHub es el mas conocido pero solo permite subir proyectos públicos de forma gratuita, los otros 4 permiten subir proyectos públicos y privados gratis.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Ricardo, lo pondré en práctica.